# Pinning powershell icon in task manager through powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I have a PS script to pinning PowerShell icon in the task manager, I am getting the below error. I have no idea since I am beginner. Below is my PS script. Wondering if anyone could help me to fix this issue.  Thanks!

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:1

- $Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:14 char:1

- $Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:15 char:1

- $Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:20 char:1

- $Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

---

```
$Target="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
if (!(Test-Path $Target)) {
    Write-Warning "$Target does not exist"
    break
}
$KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
$KeyPath2  = "*"
$KeyPath3  = "shell"
$KeyPath4  = "{:}"
$ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
$ValueData = (Get-ItemProperty ("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin")).ExplorerCommandHandler   
$Key2 = (Get-Item $KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($KeyPath2, $true)
$Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
$Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
$Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
$Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
$Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")
$Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
if ($Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) {
    $Key2.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath3)
}
```

Comment: @marsze
Hi Marsze,

I have changed the "shell" to "shellex", but no luck. Can you please tell me how to create a key. I have no idea how to create. I am looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: You already know how, you have `CreateSubKey` in your code ;)

Comment: It seems to me you have simply copied the code from another source. You should make a minimal effort to understand what the code is doing. As I said, everything you need is literally already there. We can help you here, but we won't write all of the code for you.